# Double sum that grows at sublinear rate

Tags: asymptotics

Is there an example of a non-zero function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the following term is sublinear (or $o(n)$)?

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^j f(i)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work the other way around: You want:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{1 \le j \le n} s(j)
     = o(n)
\end{align*}$

Here $s(j)$ is your inner sum. This means $s(j) = o(1)$. This requires in turn:

$\begin{align*}
   \sum_{1 \le i \le j} f(i)
     = o(1)
\end{align*}$

But this is impossible, as the last sum is at least it's first term, it can't go down as $j$ increases.